# How to fix main method not being executed in java, when no error is showing?

Tags: java, xml, spring, legacy

I have created a bean through XML for account. My main method should at the moment just print the constructor-args I've added to this bean. The program runs without errors, but main is not executing, so I have no output in the console.

It is a spring legacy project (simple maven), and has a H2 database which is currently empty as I haven't used it.

I have checked my main method with a print after each line, none are printing so I don't think it is hitting the method at all.

I've checked my beans.xml, and the design seems to have been created successfully. I've double checked my pom.xml to make sure I have the correct groupId. I've also right click on the mainApp file and gone to run as - run configurations, main and made sure it's including system files. In here it has main class marked as h2.console.

MainApp.java

```
package com.r00107892.bank;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.r00107892.bank.domain.Account;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main() {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ("beans.xml");
        Account account = (Account) context.getBean("account");
        System.out.println(account);
    }
}
```

beans.xml

```
<bean class="com.r00107892.bank.domain.AccountImplementation" id="account">
    <constructor-arg name = "accountNumber" value="1"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name = "balance" value="1000"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name = "overdraft" value="500"></constructor-arg>
</bean>'''
```

I expect to see the properties of the bean printed, instead my console just shows the cursor, like it's waiting for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main method's signature is wrong. It should be `public static void main(String[] args)`

The constructor args tag in your xml configuration will pass the corresponding value to the constructor of the parent bean's class, which is `AccountInformation` in your code. It doesn't get passed to the `main` method, the `main` method's parameter is always of type `String[]`.

Your `AccountInformation` class needs a constructor like this:

```
AccountInformation(int accountNumber, int balance, int overdraft)
```

Note: the arguments don't have to be integers. They can be any compatible type. See this for more information:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-ctor-arguments-resolution

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it. Hit another error but it wasn't show it before so progress.